# Visual studio 2010 Ultimate with MVC 4 extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have recently installed the required MVC 4 extenstion in visual studio 2010 from the below link, But I am still not able to see the MVC 4 or use it when I go to create new project. please I am new to this MVC and I know that MVC 4 comes by default with VS 2012 and for using it under VS 2010, you need to install the required mvc 4 extention that I have already installed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
MVC4 Extention download link:    http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you specifically look under web projects?

Comment: Yes, I have looked under web project, and it only shows project for MVC 2.0

Comment: Did you restart visual studio after installing it?